# Double Integral : changing variables

Tags: matrices, integration

What i need to compute is the area of a parallelogram doing a variables change from the basic coordinates to the parallelogram coordinates. The corners of the parallelogram are (1,1),(2,3),(5,3) and (6,5). The final answer should be 6.
Here is what i did :

(u,v)=H(x,y)

(x,y)=G(u,v)=H^-1(u,v)

H1=x+2y

H2=4x+2y

Then the jacobian of H is -6. Then we can get the jacobian of G which is 1/(jacobian of H)=-1/6.

Then we have our area=$\int_0^1 \, \mathrm dx$ ($\int_0^1 1*|-1/6| \, \mathrm dy$) =1/6, which is not the attended result.

If i had used the jacobian of H that would work but when i do another variable change which is 
u=2x-y
and v=x-2y i have to use tje jacobian of G if i want it to work.
Moreover in my lesson it's written that i have to use the jacobian of G but can you explain me why in my case it doesn't work.

Thank you

Comment: The integral should be done in the uv coordinate system not xy for one, also is one of those points wrong because I don't see a parallelogram in those points

Comment: I believe you are correct about the first issue, but the vertices of the parallelogram are all right (the sides follow lines $ \ x - 2y = c \  $ and $ \ 2x - y = c \ . $ [ I wasn't sure at first about this being a parallelogram at first either...]

Comment: @Dan This is a parallelogram i rechecked.

Comment: Yeah my bad I looked at it too quickly and for some reason didn't see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I can confirm that the area of the parallelogram is 6 , since the sides are parallel to the vectors $ \ \overrightarrow{a}  = \langle 1 , 2 \rangle \ $ and $ \ \overrightarrow{b}  = \langle 4 , 2 \rangle \ $ , and we find that $ \ || \overrightarrow{a} \times \overrightarrow{b} || = 6 \ . $

In the usual way the area would be calculated by double integral, the parallelogram can be turned into a rectangle by using

$$ \ u = 2x - y = 1 \ , \ u = 7 \ ,\ v = x - 2y = -1 \ , \ \text{and} \ v = -4 \ . $$

The area of the $ \ uv- $ rectangle is then $ \ (7 - 1) \cdot ([-1]-[-4] ) \ = \ 6 \cdot 3 = 18 \ $ and the matrix of partial derivatives is

$$ \ D  = \left|\begin{array}{cc}2&-1\\1&-2\end{array}\right| \  = -3 \ , $$
 the negative sign indicating that the transformation reverses the orientation of the parallelogram.  So the Jacobian gives $ \ \frac{1}{D} = -\frac{1}{3} \ $ and the area of the $ \ xy- $ parallelogram is then $ \ 18 \ \cdot \ | -\frac{1}{3} | \ = \ 6 \ .   $

I believe that because you are using the vectors for the sides *as* the basis for the variable transformation, with their lengths each taken as $ \ 1 \ $ , you find the area of a square of side $ 1 $ in $ \ uv-  $ coordinates.  Since you haven't shown the details, I am filling in that you used a transformation of $ \langle 1 , 2 \rangle \ \rightarrow \ \langle 0 , 1 \rangle \ $ and $ \langle 4 , 2 \rangle \ \rightarrow \ \langle 1 , 0 \rangle \ $ , which suggests that the transformation actually runs something like $ \ x = 4u + v \ $ and $ \ y = 2u + 2v \  , $ which produces a Jacobian

$$ \ J  = \left|\begin{array}{cc}4&1\\2&2\end{array}\right| \  = \ 6 \ , $$

and so an area for the parallelogram in $ \ xy- $ coordinates of $ \ 1 \cdot 6 = 6 \ . $  [If the transformation is instead $ \langle 1 , 2 \rangle \ \rightarrow \ \langle 1 , 0 \rangle \ $ and $ \langle 4 , 2 \rangle \ \rightarrow \ \langle 0 , 1 \rangle \ $ , then we have $ \ x = u + 4v \ $ and $ \ y = 2u + 2v \  , $ and the orientation of the parallelogram is reversed, yielding a Jacobian of $ \ -6 \ $ , again giving the area of the parallelogram as $ \ 6 \ . $ ]

$$ \\  $$

**ADDENDUM (6/7):**

Now that you have noted the transformation you have been using, it is possible to resolve the apparent conflict.  Inverting what you show in your comment, we have

$$ \begin{array}{cc} x = -\frac{1}{3} u + \frac{2}{3} v \\ y = \frac{1}{3} u - \frac{1}{6} v\ \end{array}  \ \rightarrow \  \begin{array}{cc} u =  x + 4y \\ v = 2x + 2y\ \end{array} \ . $$

This maps the points

$$ \ (1,1) , (2,3) , (5,3) , (6,5) \ $$

in the $ \ xy- $ plane to the points in the $ \ uv- $ plane

$$ \ (5,4) , (14,10) , (17,16) , (26,22) \  . $$

As we should expect, this *does* produce a parallelogram, one with reversed orientation, but with its sides parallel to the vectors  $ \ \overrightarrow{c}  = \langle 12 , 12 \rangle \ $ and $ \ \overrightarrow{d}  = \langle 9 , 6 \rangle \ $ . The area of this parallelogram is found from the length of the cross product $ \ || \overrightarrow{c} \times \overrightarrow{d} || = 36 \ . $

Now things fit together:  your Jacobian is $ \ -\frac{1}{6} \ $ , with the negative sign representing the orientation reversal and the area of the parallelogram back in the $ \ xy- $ plane is $ \ 36 \ \cdot \ | -\frac{1}{6} | \ = \ 6 \ .   $

It appears that you got turned around somewhere in working out your transformation variables, since the present ones do not produce a unit square.

Comment: Thank you for answering, i perfectly understood the first way to do with the variable change u=2x-y and v=x-2y that's what my teacher has done. But i don't understand why my way doesn't work, try to reason like i did to understand my foul, what i did is to get the jacobian of H(x,y), but i can't place it in the double integral because it is function of (x,y) and in my integral everything should be function of (u,v). Then i get the jacobian of G which is det(G)=[|1/det(H)|] gived in function of (u,v). And since det(G) is just a number(no variables x,y) we do not have to do a variable change.

Comment: When i try to have (x,y)=G(u,v) i don't find the same as you(x= u+ 4v , y= 2u + 2v). I find x=-1/3u + 2/3v and y=1/3u - 1/6v. Maybe the problem is coming from here because when i do the jacobian of this matrix i again find -1/6 which is verifying my first result. With your variable change we don't arrive to a square of side 1.

Comment: Thank you for posting the transformation you were using.  As I was coming to suspect, you somehow got your mapping running the other way around.  I have amended my discussion:  you do have the right Jacobian, but the wrong parallelogram.

Comment: No, our transformations still not fit. You find that x=-1/3u + 2/3v and y=1/3u - 1/6v implies u=x+4y and v=2x+2y, and what i have is u=x+2y and v=4x+2y which is completely different i think the foul come from here ( maybe i don't know how to find the inverse variable change).

Comment: Adding _your_ transformation equations together gives $ \ x + y = \frac{1}{2} v \ \Rightarrow \ v = 2x + 2y \ . $  Adding your equation for $ \ x \ $ to four times the equation for $ \ y \ $ gives $ \ \frac{3}{3} u \ . $  Are you sure you've been using your equations consistently?  The equations $ \ u = x + 2y \ $ and $ \ v = 4x + 2y \ $ _do not_ follow from the equations in the first line of your note...

Comment: To get my equation i just inverted my matrix (-1/3,2/3 \n 1/3,-1/6) and i obtained (1,2 \n 4,2). Is it a wrong way ?

Comment: OK, now we have the root of the disagreement -- your inverse _is_ incorrect; you should have (1,4 \n 2,2) .  Check the methods for inverting a 2-by-2 matrix again...

Comment: Okay i'll do this, hope i will get why the hell i don't do it right.